# Get the count of the times date is inserted to know the last for loop iteration in Node.js

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I want to insert the stockid's in the database in a different row and I am using a for loop. I also want to know the last iteration, but because of the async of javascript I am having trouble getting this to work. The current output is that `j` only increasing by 1 and print 4 times. I will appreciate any assistance or recommendation. Thanks.

```
var order_id = 827283383;
var stockid = [1,2,3,4];
for(i = 0; i < stockid.length; i++)  {
  db.query("insert into order_detail( order_id, stock_id) values ('" + order_id + "','" + stockid[i] + "') ;",  function (err, rs) {
    var j = 0;
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
    else{
      j++; // aimed to use as a counter 
      console.log(j);  
    }
    if(j < stockid.length-1){ //aimed to get last iteration
      console.log('This is the last row');
    }
  });  
}
```

Only one output return when the data is `select` in `then`. code below:

```
const query = promisify(db.query.bind(db));
Promise.all(stockid.map(id => query("insert into order_detail( order_id, stock_id) values ('" + order_id + "','" + id + "') ;")))
                    .then(
                      db.query('select *, order_detail.order_id as orderid from  sodiq_business.order_detail  join sodiq_business.order  on sodiq_business.order.order_id = sodiq_business.order_detail.order_id join sodiq_business.stock on sodiq_business.stock.stock_id = sodiq_business.order_detail.stock_id join sodiq_business.customer on sodiq_business.customer.id = sodiq_business.stock.seller_id join sodiq_business.product on sodiq_business.product.prod_id = sodiq_business.stock.prod_id where order_detail.order_id = ?',[order_id],  function (err, rs) {
                        if (err) {
                          console.log(err);
                        }
                        else{
                            console.log(rs)
                        })
```

Comment: You are reinitializing `j` to zero for every query call.

Comment: I feel embarrassed to have missed that. Thanks so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by @Tapler in the comment, your j sets to 0 in every iteration. Make it like

```
var order_id = 827283383;
var stockid = [1,2,3,4];
var j = 0;
for(i = 0; i < stockid.length; i++)  {
  db.query(`insert into order_detail( order_id, stock_id) values (${order_id},${stockid[i]})`,  function (err, rs) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
    else{
      j++; // aimed to use as a counter 
      console.log(j);  
    }
    if(j < stockid.length-1){ //aimed to get last iteration
      console.log('This is the last row');
    }
  });  
}
```

Also read about Prepared statements and SQL Injection to avoid attacks on the database. This is very much prone to database attacks.

Comment: I am also aware of the sql injection am just in a testing phase. Thanks for mentioning it and providing a work around. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest you to promisify `db.query`:

```
const { promisify } = require('util');

const query = promisify(db.query.bind(db));

Promise.all(stockid.map(id => query("insert into order_detail( order_id, stock_id) values ('" + order_id + "','" + id + "') ;")))
    .then(console.log)
    .catch(console.error);
```

Comment: This look more cooler. But can I use the inserted data immediately after the insertion? I want to `select` inserted data immediately after the insertion.

Comment: Then you need to use this, in the `then` the data is immediately available while it's not in your code because you dont wait for the asynchronous query to return

Comment: Thanks so much. I will surely consider using this. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I am sorry to bother you again, when I select the data in `then`, only one output is returned (the first inserted data). I added my code to my question if you have any suggestion. Thanks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219698/discussion-between-guerric-p-and-naheem-olaniyan).